# Truffle - multiple transactions per block

Tags: truffle, blocks, truffle-test

i try to simulate a large transaction load and therefore want to execute multiple transactions in a truffle test. I changed the block-time to five seconds and generate the transactions, but only one transaction per block is executed.

Here is my code:
[image]

And here the ganache blocks. Every block with only one transaction, i would like to have all 10 transactions in a single block.

[image]

I really need help, i dont understand the problem. I am able to get two transactions in a block when i manually send ether with metamask, but not with the truffle test.

**EDIT - solved:**
I changed the code to web3.eth.Contract and call the method with Contract.methods.myFunction(..), now it works but i dont know why ^^:
[image]

Comment: That configuration should be supported by ganache. What does your configuration look like? Did you restart the ganache instance?

Comment: var truffleConfig = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: '127.0.0.1', 
            port: 7545,         
            network_id: "*", 
            websockets: true
        }
    }
};

Comment: but i think the truffle code is the problem

Comment: Default ganache config only accepts 1 transaction per block, if you changed it and restarted it should accept more than one. Truffle should just work without any change, but it depends on the test if you await then the 5 seconds will elapse and a block will be created anyway. In your test you are not waiting for the transaction, the 2 seconds timeout might pass before they are mined, you have to use something like Promise.all to wait for all transactions.

Comment: ganache was not the problem, something with my truffle code was wrong, but i found a workaround